# OpenGL ES 2.0 Failing to correctly assign the color attribute

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm struggling a bit to apply the color for my geometry. When I specify it directly in the vertex shader (*"varColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 1.0);"*) - everything is ok. But if I use color values from the "**vColor**" attribue - everything gets messed up.

(*Added some screenshots to show what I mean*)

Can someone help me to figure out what am I doing wrong, or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

**Using "varColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 1.0);"**
[image: Using "varColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 1.0);"]

**Using "varColor = vColor"**
[image: Using "varColor = vColor"]

Vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;
attribute vec4 vColor;

varying lowp vec4 varColor;
varying mediump vec2 varTexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vPosition;
    varTexCoord = vTexCoord;
//  varColor    = vColor;
    varColor    = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D Texture0;

varying vec4 varColor;
varying vec2 varTexCoord;

void main() 
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture0, varTexCoord) * varColor;
}
```

After shader is linked, I'm binding my attributes like this:

```
mMatrixMVP = glGetUniformLocation(mProgramId, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");

glBindAttribLocation(mProgramId, 0, "vPosition");
glBindAttribLocation(mProgramId, 1, "vTexCoord");
glBindAttribLocation(mProgramId, 2, "vColor");

mTexture = glGetUniformLocation(mProgramId, "Texture0");
glUniform1i(mTexture, 0);
```

Structure that holds my vertex information:

```
struct Vertex
{
   float         xyz[3];
   float         st[2];
   unsigned char color[4]; // All assigned to value of 255
};
```

When rendering, after vertex buffer is bound, I'm setting vertex attributes like this:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) offsetof(Vertex, xyz));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) offsetof(Vertex, st));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) offsetof(Vertex, color));

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
pTexture->Bind(); // Just a "glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);"
glUniform1i(mpCurrentShader->GetTexture(), 0);
```

After this I'm binding the index buffer and calling "glDrawElements".

Then, calling `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` and disabling all attributes with "glDisableVertexAttribArray" and finally - calling `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`

Comment: If I understand your screenshot correctly, you have problems with your texture coordinates rather than (or in addition to) vertex color. Actually *using* a vertex attribute in a shader will make it *active*, and will change the automatically assigned locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `glBindAttribLocation()` calls **before** linking the shader program.

If you link a program without specifying the location of attributes with either `glBindAttribLocation()`, or with `layout` qualifiers in the shader code, the attribute locations will be assigned automatically when the shader program is linked. If you call `glBindAttribLocation()` after linking the program, the new locations will only take effect if you link the shader program again.